# Gremlin server with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to use [gremlin-server](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop) by tinkerpop. I am not able to launch a gremlin server with neo4j.

The documentation says.

*Note that TinkerPop does not include Neo4j dependencies in its distributions.  To use this file, please ensure that Neo4j dependencies are installed into Gremlin Server's path with gremlin-server.sh -i org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.y.z*

I have already installed the neo4j-gremlin using **:install**, as **-i** is said to be deprecated.

Still, I am getting the following error, on the following command

```
.\bin\gremlin-server.bat .\conf\gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml
```

ERROR

```
    [WARN] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/neo4j-empty.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not find [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph] - Ensure that the jar is in the classpath
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not find [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph] - Ensure that the jar is in the classpath
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:105)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:84)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:111)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:355)
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.jsr223.Neo4jGremlinPlugin
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.initializeGremlinScriptEngineManager(GremlinExecutor.java:444)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:103)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.<init>(GremlinExecutor.java:72)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor$Builder.create(GremlinExecutor.java:586)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:84)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:111)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:355)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.jsr223.Neo4jGremlinPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.initializeGremlinScriptEngineManager(GremlinExecutor.java:407)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: what is in your `GREMLIN_SERVER_INSTALL/ext` directory? do you see the neo4j directory and related files? also, you mentioned using `gremlin-server.sh` but then also specified use of the `.bat` to start - is this a windows environment or something else?

Comment: I am using Windows environment. I couldn't find the neo4j directory in the /ext folder. But those files were installed in the Gremlin console. A simple copying from the console directory to the server directory was the fix.
Thanks for the direction.

Comment: are you saying that `gremlin.bat :install` puts the neo4j jars in a directory other than `GREMLIN_SERVER_INSTALL/ext`?

Comment: `gremlin-server.bat :install` doesnot work at all. That's the problem. That's why I couldn't install the neo4j dependencies into the gremlin server. So, I was trying to install neo4j from the console side and that worked. Then I copied the neo4j folder from gremlin console to the server

Answer (score 2):

`:install` is the console command.

`install` is the server command.  `-i` also still works.

Answer (score 0):

As a committer of the gremlin-python-tutorial github project my answer would be to look at the relevant lines of the

https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/gremlin-python-tutorial/blob/master/run

script.

```
  version=3.4.3
  plugin=neo4j-gremlin
  gsd=apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-${version}
  if [ ! -d $gsd/ext/$plugin ]
  then
    color_msg $blue "installing plugin $plugin"
    $gsd/bin/gremlin-server.sh install org.apache.tinkerpop $plugin $version
  else
    color_msg $green "$plugin plugin already installed"
  fi
  color_msg $blue "starting neo4j gremlin-server ..."
  conf=$(realpath $gsd/conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml)
  $gsd/bin/gremlin-server.sh $conf
```

In the Neo4J section of http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Gremlin_python#Connecting_to_Gremlin_enabled_graph_databases you'll find the explanation

Please not the check whether the ext directory contains the installation (see Stephen Mallette's question in a comment above).